# Azure Frontdoor WAF policy is blocking requests even though I have rule disabled

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-waf

I have a `Microsoft.Network/FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2019-10-01` policy for my web app. I pass in a token via the URL for some requests and *sometimes* this token has a double hyphen `--` which means that Azure thinks this is a SQL injection attack.

I have tried disabling that rule that's causing it but the request still gets blocked. [image]

So you can see in the photo that it tells me in Azure portal which rule is responsible for blocking my request.

So this is the resource I have and I have tried a few different things in attempt to fix this issue but this is the last thing I have tried.

```
resource wafPolicy 'Microsoft.Network/FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2019-10-01' = {
  name: wafPolicyName
  location: frontdoorLocation
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    policySettings: {
      mode: 'Prevention'
      enabledState: 'Enabled'
    }
    managedRules: {
      managedRuleSets: [
        {
          ruleSetType: 'DefaultRuleSet'
          ruleSetVersion: '1.0'
          ruleGroupOverrides: [
            {
              ruleGroupName: 'SQLI'
              rules: [
                {
                  ruleId: '942200'
                  enabledState: 'Disabled'
                  action: 'Block'
                }
                {
                  ruleId: '942440'
                  enabledState: 'Disabled'
                  action: 'Allow'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
          exclusions: [
            {
              matchVariable: 'RequestCookieNames'
              selectorMatchOperator: 'Equals'
              selector: 'access-token'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I set rule `942440` to `ALLOW` instead of `BLOCK` and it still blocks the request. What am I missing? How can the request still be blocked?

Does it have something to do with `enabledState`?

Comment: Try to create another separate rule for 942440 and give allow action

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? I’m not sure I follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create exclusion for the specific query string against SQL injection rules. This is a safer way for the purpose which you mentioned. See documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-waf-configuration?tabs=portal